# show one column in three columns in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression, reporting, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS report which shows the different number of records based on the parameters. the result is two columns but 60 rows or more, I tried to show my dataset result in six columns instead of two columns to be more user friendly and to utilize the empty space.
I have three `tablix` and each `tablix` points so same dataset and same columns but I applied this expression on the `row visibility`
first `tablix`'s expression is

```
=IIF((RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 3) = 1, False, True)
```

the second `tablix`'s expression is

```
=IIF((RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 3) = 2, False, True)
```

the last `tablix`'s expression is

```
=IIF((RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 3) = 0, False, True)
```

the result I get is

```
T01 65       T02 85         T03 21
T04 85       T05 89         T06 85
T07 87       T08 85         T09 85
```

Is there any way I can show my result as :

```
T01 65       T04 85         T07 87
T02 85       T05 89         T08 85
T03 21       T06 85         T09 85
```

Answer (score 0):

SSRS has this built in.  Under report properties on the layout tab.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159107.aspx

So one approach is to use multiple tablix with a filter that checks RowNumber and accordingly displays particular records in each table.

The other way is called **Newsletter-style report** [(link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms159107(v=sql.105)). This formatting is retained only when  report is exported as PDF or Image. It can be previewed only when you select 'Print Layout' on the Preview tab in Visual Studio. Here is an example:

1. Create a new report with the foll. dataset: `SELECT ID,NAME FROM TABLENAME`
2. Add a new table to the report and select the ID and Name as columns
3. Click on the tablix and press F4 to edit the tablix properties. In the properties window, change the Size - set the width to 2in
4. Click on the report area outside the report page boundary and press F4 to edit the report properties. In the properties window, change the Column value to 3, and column spacing value to 0.1
5. On the report scroll to the right hand side, you will notice that there are 2 new columns (so totally 3 columns on the report - because you selected 3 in step 4 above). Now click on the margin at the start of the column 2 and pull it further to the left to bring it as close to the column 1. This is only to reduce the need for huge page size.
6. Right click on the report area outside the report page boundary and select Report Properties. Change the Page Size - Set the width to 10in
7. Preview the report. Now select the 'Print Layout' tab to see the result. This formatting is retained only when  report is exported as PDF or Image.

As noted in points 5 and 6 - since the report body flows into multiple columns, you must ensure that the page size is at-least equal to -> ([Original report body  size times the number of columns] + all the column spacing values). Otherwise it will look messy.

Comment: I don't see columns option in report properties

Comment: Notice in the article that they references the properties window.  This is different from right clicking the report and choosing report properties.

Comment: At the top of the properties window that allows you to select report or items under the report.  When I open a report and do not click on any report elements, report is in the drop down by default.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a multi-column or "newsletter style" report, but it only works correctly when rendering to a PDF or other image format. You could also look into putting three tablix controls side-by-side and using some paging function to divide the number of rows evenly among them. Here's an example from an [article on technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23811.paging-a-query-with-sql-server.aspx):

```
-- 2 - QUERY USING "ROW_NUMBER"
DECLARE @PageNumber AS INT, @RowspPage AS INT
SET @PageNumber = 2
SET @RowspPage = 10 
SELECT * FROM (
             SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID_EXAMPLE) AS Numero,
                    ID_EXAMPLE, NM_EXAMPLE , DT_CREATE FROM TB_EXAMPLE
               ) AS TBL
WHERE Numero BETWEEN ((@PageNumber - 1) * @RowspPage + 1) AND (@PageNumber * @RowspPage)
ORDER BY ID_EXAMPLE
GO
```